# Erase unwanted characters

Tags: c++

We have created a char array with a fixed length. Now, we write a word or a sentence inside that array. However, the length of this word-sentence is shorter than the length of the char array, so when we print the message with printf function, a number of crap characters are also printed. We would like to erase all this characters, even if the length of the message written is variable. 
Thank you!

Comment: Strings must be null terminated (i.e. must end with `\0`) (p.s: next time provide the code instead of describing what you want your code to do, the two don't always match)

Comment: @Borgleader: Answers go down there buddy ↓↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: ..............................................................<insert answer here>

Answer (score 3):

C strings are terminated by a NUL byte (`'\0'`). If you don't have this terminator then `printf` doesn't know that your string has ended. The solution is to put a `\0` after your word in the array.

Note: learn to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) which manages this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered not using a fixed array size if that is not what you want? You could just use a `char*` instead and assign it's size dynamically.

If you want a fixed size for some reason the only solution I can come up with is to track in a separate variable how long the word is and then only print the n first characters. There is no way to determine which chars are valid and which are not in the array as far as I know.

Comment: Don't use a `char*`. Don't dynamically allocate `char` buffers. We have had library facilities to do this for us since 1998.

Answer (score 0):

Other than that, if your buffer is supposed to be just a byte array and not a (null terminated) string, then you can use fwrite instead of fprintf to dump the contents.

But in general, I agree with others that it could be better to use std::string.